# Add line break to values in javascript array

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I have a question and answer website that I created using Ionic v1. My problem is that I am trying to add a `<br><br/>` to to my "question" in one of my objects but I can't get it to work. I've tried adding "\n" which didn't work. I also tried this:

```
var quizArray = string.split('~');
var finalString = quizArray.join('<br/>');

document.getElementById('yourIdHere').innerHTML = finalString;
```

which didn't work as well. Any got any other methods to add a line break to a specific value in my array? Here is my code

**Javascript**

```
var marksman = [{
"question": "The 13 American colonies<br><br/>belonged to what European power?",
    "answer1": "Prussia",
    "answer2": "Great Britain",
    "answer3": "France",
    "answer4": "Spain",
    "correctAnswer": "Great Britain",
    "explanation": "After defeating the French and Spanish during the Seven Years War, Great Britain controlled not only the original 13 colonies but also all of America east of the Mississippi River except for New Orleans.",

}];
```

**HTML**

```
<h2 style="color:#32575E;" class="question" id="question"></h2>
```

Comment: Please consider to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if possible. This way, it's more likely volunteers on SO can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Does your string really include `~` in the places you want to break the line, your code seems to work:

```js
var string = "line 1~line 2";
var quizArray = string.split('~');
var finalString = quizArray.join('<br/>');

document.getElementById('yourIdHere').innerHTML = finalString;
```

```html
<div id="yourIdHere"></div>
```

You can just replace the `~` with `<br/>`:

```js
var string = "line 1~line 2";
var finalString = string.replace("~", "<br/>");

document.getElementById('yourIdHere').innerHTML = finalString;
```

```html
<div id="yourIdHere"></div>
```

Comment: This really should be a comment, not an answer, as it's a request for more info from OP. And if it's not reproducible, you should cast a close vote.

Comment: the "string" variable should be my one of the objects in my array. I tried "marksman[1].replace" but that didn't work